# Why doesn't my laptop battery charge while the laptop is in use?

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, charging

Up until a week ago, my laptop has always been able to charge the battery while I'm using it.  Now, it will not charge unless the computer is sleeping, hibernating, or turned off.  The icon in the start tray states that the battery is charging but it is not animated (it used to be) and of course the power level does not increase.

Otherwise, the battery seems to be fine.  The battery life is decent (2h+) and while the laptop is in use and plugged in the battery will maintain a constant charge.

Any troubleshooting help would be great (i.e. is this a charger issue, battery issues, software issue, etc...)

Comment: Its possible your power adapter is failing and can no longer supply enough amps to run the PC and charge it at the same time. Charging is controlled by a controller board inside the laptop.

Comment: is the charger the *original* one that came with the laptop when you purchased it? Also, is your laptop still covered under warranty?

Comment: Does the operating system make a difference, and does it matter if you have logged in yet (to test the operating system bit, you don't actually need a whole OS, a windows install disk will work, just boot into that, and then plug in the machine. wait, and see if it changes).

Answer (score 3):

I'd check the power adapter first. Does it have any physical damage? If so, you should replace it. Does the battery charge if you use a different adapter? (Buy a second or borrow one from someone with the same laptop.)